# Back button in title bar?

Tags: android, layout

I want to put one back button in title bar area to go on back activity in Android app how to put that button.

[image]

Like there is in this image.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is some of your code you are having trouble with? Don't come here expecting this community to do your work for you.

Comment: i don't even know how to modify title bar that's why i am asking Dude.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assign a parent Activity in `Manifest.xml` like this :

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- The meta-data element is needed for versions lower than 4.1 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Then in Activity's `onCreate()`:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And at last in `onOptionsItemSelected` :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

Here is more if you need :

[Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)

Comment: Okies Man... Thank You.. :) For Android Docs